# Selenium chromedriver 2.25 TimeoutException cannot determine loading status

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using `python3` on mac os and I have updated chrome, `chromedriver` and `selenium` to the latest version. I am getting a `TimeoutException`, the browser opens correctly but it freezes.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# opens browser with blank page
>>> driver.get('http://example.com')
# gets first page OK and then driver literally flashes once
>>> driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
>>>
# Cursor loading forever... until TimeoutException
```

This error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: cannot determine loading status
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.003
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426935 (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64)
```

I'm using: `Python 3.5.2` ,`Chrome 54.0`, `chromedriver 2.25`, `selenium 3.0.1`

I've tried other versions of `chromedriver` with no success, also I did not find any solution to this online. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Still getting the error from above + getting a new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from unknown error: bad inspector message: {"method":"Page.loadEventFired","params":{"timestamp":14220,088073}}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426935 (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64)
```

Comment: Incrementing page load time worked for me. driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

Answer (score 11):

> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: cannot determine loading status
>   from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.003

[Issue817:It looks like this issue has been logged as a bug for Selenium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=817).

Someone has answered to get rid from this issue by using the `--dns-prefetch-disable` option of chrome.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')
driver = Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

[If issue still exists follow this thread may be it solves your problem](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9007/how-to-handle-time-out-receiving-message-from-the-renderer-in-chrome-driver)

Comment: Using `--dns-prefetch-disable` didn't solve the issue for me. The driver is created with it's arguments correctly but with the next command [webdriver hangs on page load and does not give control back for script execution.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=402)

Comment: For the last line, you meant to write `driver = Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)`

Answer (score 0):

Set

env LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ./chromedriver

from : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1552

Comment: I don't see how this helps.